# Extract string between nth character and another nth character

Tags: java, substring

When I tried to just load game's my whole map into memory it got a bit bigger than I wanted.  I am trying to break the map into chunks.  My game's map is comma delimited.  A sample part of the map string: "0, 0, 45, 32, 3, 3, 0, 0,".

Currently I am using the following but it takes like 9 seconds(my maps are huge).

```
String[] mapArr = map.split(", ");
short[] groundLayer = new short[chunkWidth * chunkHeight];
//code that fills in the groundLayer array
```

9 seconds of waiting in game if the player walks too far in 1 direction will not work.

My thought was to do something where I substring from the 'map String' from comma (int firstComma) to comma (int lastComma).

```
firstComma = characterX + (characterY * mapWidth);
lastComma = firstComma + (chunkWidth * chunkHeight);
```

Then I would split (", ") only that resulting substring.  Is this a good idea performance wise?

What is the most efficent way to do something like this?  Substring, regex, indexOf, something different?  Any help would be so much appreciated.

---

***EDIT*** Providing more context below:

My map is made up of multiple layers and I used 'Tiled' to draw/export them.  Here is how I read from the file and save them into short array.  Rather than splitting the whole map String, I am trying to only split from character X to character Y.

```
try {
    String map = readFile("res/images/tiles/MyFirstMap-building-p.json");
    String[] strArr = map.split(", ");

    buildingLayer = new short[chunkWidth * chunkHeight];
    short arrayIndex = 0;
    for(short y = 0; y < chunkHeight; y++) {
        for(short x = 0; x < chunkWidth; x++) {
            //get the absolute position of the cell
            short cellX = (short) (characterX + x - chunkWidth / 2);
            short cellY = (short) (characterY + y - chunkHeight / 2);
            if(cellX >= 0 && cellX < mapWidth && cellY >= 0 && cellY < mapHeight) { //within bounds
                buildingLayer[arrayIndex] = Short.parseShort(strArr[cellX + (cellY * mapWidth)]);
            } else { //out of bounds, put down a placeholder
                buildingLayer[arrayIndex] = 0;
            }
            arrayIndex++;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.fatal("ReadMapFile(building)", e);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(theDesktop, getStringChecked("message_file_locks") + "\n\n" + e.getMessage(), getStringChecked("message_error"), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(1);
}


private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
    try {
        FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
        return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
    }
    finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a random access file? You'll calculate the location of each block in it and read that, no need to load it all to memory

Comment: If you store really big data, why do you store it as strings? Everything would be far more efficient if you created something like a binary format for your maps. This way, you'd only store the data (and compute the data) you really need - and not unnecessary String overhead.

Comment: well it is in the following format.. 0, 0, 3, 0, 2,... Can I extract it as a short array directly, using split?

Comment: for lack of knowing a better way, I'd assume...

Comment: screw strings, store it as binary. Loading it as string is not a very clever idea. You'll need to make some editor for it ofc but then if the map is large, you'll need to anyway

Comment: Also you might try to use my `Ion` library, if you'll take the time to read thru the javadocs. It could work nicely for storing your map. [LINK](https://github.com/MightyPork/mightyutils/tree/master/src/mightypork/utils/ion) (sorry that there's no tutorial for it)

Comment: Writing it as a fixed format file is probably best if it is "huge". You might try using a `Scanner` around a `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: I apologize, I tried to present too low level of a question when I needed high level help - sorry to potentially waste your time.  I think I have all I need in the edits now for you to be able to properly guide me.  Would it make more sense to grab what I need before I even load the file?  Aka only grab from firstComma-lastComma when I call ReadFile(changing ReadFile to accept start index, end index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I went with (I removed lots of the looping logic for simplicity purposes).  Thanks @Elliott Frisch for the help in the comments.

```
private static short[] scanMapFile(String path, int[] leftChunkSides, int[] rightChunkSides) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
    scanner.useDelimiter(", ");

    short[] tmpMap = new short[chunkWidth * chunkHeight];
    int count = 0;

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        tmpMap[count] = scanner.nextShort();    
        count++;
    }

    scanner.close();
    return tmpMap;
}
```